# Scrapy/Selenium jumps twice to the next page, then breaks (element not clickable). Plus no data is extracted except on the first page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website, for which I need the program to jump on the next page until the end and extract data on each site. So far the data extraction from the start page works, also the automatic jump on page 2 and 3.

1. After the first two jumps, the program stops, because *element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (904, 603). Other element would receive the click*. I don't understand it, since the first 2 clicks worked fine.
2. the program only extracts the needed data (callback) on the first page, but not on the following. Any idea why?

   ```
   def parse(self, response):
    url = 'xxxx'
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/xxxx/chromedriver')
    self.driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10) # gives an implicit wait for 10 seconds
    self.driver.get(url)

    while self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("body > div.container-fluid.main-container.bg-white.py-5 > section.maincontent.row > div > nav:nth-child(11) > ul > li:nth-child(7) > a"):

        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)

        single_joboffer = response.xpath(".//div[@class='col-12 col-md-10']/p[@class='inserattitel h2 mt-0']/a/@href")

        for joboffer in single_joboffer:
            url1 = response.urljoin(joboffer.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url1, callback = self.parse_dir_contents)

        element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.container-fluid.main-container.bg-white.py-5 > section.maincontent.row > div > nav:nth-child(11) > ul > li:nth-child(7) > a")
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,4000)","", element)
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        sleep(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.container-fluid.main-container.bg-white.py-5 > section.maincontent.row > div > nav:nth-child(11) > ul > li:nth-child(7) > a").click()
    self.driver.close()
   ```

I've first tried using xpaths for the next button, but that did not work, since several page buttons had the same xpath, so it was randomly jumping between pages nonstop. The css-selector seems to be the way to go here. Also I played with the sleep time, but it seems to have no impact on that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem fixed: After the first two pages, the css structure changed. From the structure of the first two pages: ["|<<","previous","1","2","3","...","next",">>|"] it changed to ["|<<","previous","1","2","3","4","...","next",">>|"] from the third page on. I had to change nth-child() to nth-last-child(2), to always get the "next" button.